# How to restrict file upload from specific folder in windows xp

Tags: browser, firewall, anti-virus, upload, restrictions

I am trying to make copy protection.I can protect from edit, copy,save as actions but i can't protect from file uploading.My netowrk users shoud be some is full controll and some is only view.View user shoud be can't edit, copy,save as files.

Comment: What OS? Which browser? What type of access are you trying to restrict - read or write? Your question is not clear

Answer (score 2):

you can't limit the browser to access a folder on your system when other applications can access that folder (lets say: explorer).

there are soooooooooo many ways around that "copy protection" that i name just a few:

- copy the file to another folder
- map the folder to a different drive-name (see [subst](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx))

so, as long as you can access the file ... you can copy it.